# Is there any function in erlang to check if the list is a proplist?

Tags: erlang

I have a data in format of tuple :

```
{data, [[{a, 2}, {b, 3}], [{x, 1}, {v,2}], [1,2,3,4], "hello world", 1111]}
```

Since,

```
{data, [[{a, 2}, {b, 3}], [{x, 1}, {v,2}], [1,2,3,4], "hello world", 1111]} = {data, L}.
```

And need to check if the element of `L` is a proplist, like here : `[{a, 2}, {b, 3}]` and `[{x, 1}, {v,2}]` are proplists.

Is there any function in erlang to check whether the list is proplist?

`is_proplist(List)` should return `true` or `false`

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169139/is-proplist-in-erlang

Comment: All answers to the linked questions are wrong however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function F1 below checks for proplists (assuming that a single atom 'a' is equivalent to {'a',true})

```
1> F = fun(X) when is_atom(X) -> true; ({X,_}) when is_atom(X) -> true; (_) -> false end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.80484245>
2> L = [[{a, 2}, {b, 3}], [{x, 1}, {v,2}], [1,2,3,4], "hello world", 1111].
[[{a,2},{b,3}],[{x,1},{v,2}],[1,2,3,4],"hello world",1111]
3> F1 = fun(X) when is_list(X) -> lists:all(F,X); (_) -> false end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.80484245>
4> [X || X <- L, F1(X)].                                           
[[{a,2},{b,3}],[{x,1},{v,2}]]
5>
```